# Changing the default select color of action buttons in DetailsFragment in Leanback Library

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

[image]Hi Guys,

I want to change the color of default background color that comes on action button selection in details fragment.Any idea how the same can be acheived ?

Comment: Check and follow my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Have you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using it's `styles.xml` which is provided by `Lean Back` library.

> `Follow the steps below first`.

1. Go to your `sdk` -> `extras` -> `android` -> `support` -> `v17` -> `leanback` -> `res` -> `values`.
2. From there copy `styles.xml` file into your current leanback project folder.
3. Now you have the `style.xml` file inside your project.
4. Open that file and find below `style`.

`<style name="Widget.Leanback.DetailsActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Leanback.DetailsActionButtonStyleBase">`

Inside that you can add below property and you will have it's background color changed.

```
<item name="android:background">@color/lb_speech_orb_recording</item>
```

I have tested this my side and it's working let me know if you face any issue.

Hope this will help you to get what exactly you need.

Comment: So you are also adding all the dimens,string and drawables that leanback refers to ?

Answer (score 5):

I didn't like the idea of copying the styles.xml into my own project. The way I did it was to just provide a custom presenter in the ArrayObjectAdapter constructor. When you don't supply a presenter, then a default one is inserted for you by the DetailsOverviewRow.

```
public class ActionPresenter extends Presenter {

  @Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_action, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
  }

  @Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
    Button button = (Button) viewHolder.view;
    Action action = (Action) item;

    button.setText(action.getLabel1());
  }

  @Override public void onUnbindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder) {

  }
}
```

and the custom_action.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:lines="1"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:background="@drawable/action_selector"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    />
```

Then in the details fragment you use it like any other adapter/presenter

```
ArrayObjectAdapter actionsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ActionPresenter());
    actionsAdapter.add(new Action(0, "Watch Now"));
    actionsAdapter.add(new Action(1, "More Info"));
    row.setActionsAdapter(actionsAdapter);
```

Comment: The *button* here didn't getting focus or not clickable while going to *Video Detail* screen ? Can you suggest workaround with that ?

Comment: Get an idea from here to change the font of action button. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In other way,

It is possible to set using `DetailsOverviewRowPresenter`like this;

```
private void setupDetailsOverviewRowPresenter() {
    // Set detail background and style.
    DetailsOverviewRowPresenter detailsPresenter =
                new DetailsOverviewRowPresenter(new DetailsDescriptionPresenter());
    detailsPresenter.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.details_fragment_background_color));
}
```

Comment: this doesn't change the color of the action button. it only affects the background color of the bottom right element.